# Calculate Width and Height respecting Aspect Ratio for any given Max Width and Max Height

Tags: c#, image-resizing

I was asked to resize any picture to its equivalent thumbnail while respecting the original aspect ratio of the picture.

So far, I've only managed to accomplish this while only passing the max. width, like follows:

```
public static Size GetSizeAdjustedToAspectRatio(int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight, int dWidth, int dHeight)
{
    bool isLandscape = sourceWidth > sourceHeight;
    int fixedSize = dWidth;

    double aspectRatio = (double)sourceWidth / (double)sourceHeight; ;

    if (isLandscape)
        return new Size(fixedSize, (int)((fixedSize / aspectRatio) + 0.5));
    else
        return new Size((int)((fixedSize * aspectRatio) + 0.5), fixedSize);
}
```

I've tried several ways of calculating it so that it will accept any given max. height and max. width in order to keep the original aspect ratio on the end result picture.

Comment: Why are you adding 0.5?

Comment: To round to integer. Found on another solution on stackoverflow instead of using Math.Round

Comment: That solution is wrong: arbitrarily adding 0.5 doesn't round, just changes the value by 0.5. With a cast/conversion to `int` it is more than enough. If you want to get a specific behaviour rely on a function (`Math.Round` or `Math.Ceiling`/`Math.Floor`).

Comment: This issue aside, what is your exact problem? Your algorithm should deliver (more or less) what you want. That is: you calculate the given ratio from the old dimensions and apply this ratio to one of the new dimensions (width) to get the other one (height). Logically the new dimensions cannot perfectly match the target values, otherwise the ratio wouldn't be met. Rather than always chosing width, you might choose also height on account of the values; is this what you mean?

Comment: @varocarbas, the problem with my algorithm is that I'm fixing the values, as if the new width and new height were the same. For instance, if you have a 1600x800 image and you pass the arguments for width: 500 and height: 800, it won't work. My objective was to resize the picture, respecting the original aspect ration and the max width and max height accordingly (changing if it's landscape or portrait)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
public static Size GetSizeAdjustedToAspectRatio(int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight, int dWidth, int dHeight) {
    bool isLandscape = sourceWidth > sourceHeight;

    int newHeight;
    int newWidth;
    if (isLandscape) {
        newHeight = dWidth * sourceHeight / sourceWidth;
        newWidth = dWidth;
    }
    else {
            newWidth = dHeight * sourceWidth  / sourceHeight;
            newHeight = dHeight;
    }

    return new Size(newWidth, newHeight);
}
```

In landscape, you set the thumbnail width to the destination box width and height is found by rule of three. In portrait, you set the thumbnail height to the destination box height and calculate width.

Comment: I almost feel bad after reading your answer. Here I was trying to divise numerous solutions and it was way simpler than I had imagined. 
Thank you so much for the added explation!

Comment: Don't worry. I still remember the first time I was faced to this problem, I had the same feeling :)

Comment: Additionally, you are mixing up the variables in the calculation of the ratios. This is certainly not what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @varocarbas, yes I have already tested the code, it worked well.

Comment: @Hallaghan Firstly, this code doesn't even compile (and for various reasons). Secondly, it mixes up the picture and screen variables in the ratio calculation and thus I am completely sure that it does not deliver what you want. Now El Marce corrected it and compiles; but the mixing up continues there.

Comment: @varocarbas, I didn't just copy-paste his code... I fixed it myself. What really mattered here was the algorithm and he showed it to me, of course after hand fixing it I got it working.

Comment: @varocarbas you are fitting an image into a thumbnail. Therefore you fix the larger dimention in the thumbnail. Then the other dimention is calculated by the rule of three, obtained by the reasoning that sourceWidth / sourceHeight == dWidth / dHeight.

Comment: Sure this is what has to be done. What the OP's code was doing in a quite weird way. Sorry, but your code being so wrong since the start transmitted me a bad impression and after a quick look didn't realise that you are putting the variables in a bit weird order.

Comment: @varocarbas, my acceptance of this answer relies simply on my test cases delivering the desired results and nothing more. If you think this solution does not work, please expose your explanation. This site isn't just about the person who asks the question, it helps millions of people looking for the same thing.

Comment: @varocarbas, thanks for the sugestion, modified the order for increased readability.

Comment: @Hallaghan Sorry, as said I took a quick look at the solution and misunderstood the wrong order of the variables. This is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @varocarbas, Ah ok, no problem man. Still, thanks for wanting to help me as well. People like you and El Marce help make this site what it currently is.

Comment: It is not a big deal, but when your post is not even compiling... I don't analyse it too carefully -> other reason for posting proper codes :)